# how to call 2 stored procedure with table of data inside a stored procedure to make count of rows in it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 2 stored procedures, it has different columns from 2 different tables. I want to count the results(no. of rows) of these 2 stored procedures by creating the temporary table But I don't know how to pull this.
1st procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[setable_workflowtable]    
    @techteam nvarchar(100) = NULL    
AS    
BEGIN    
    SELECT
        s.SecurityExceptionID, s.SecurityExceptionInfoID,
        w.WorkflowID ,s.CatalogueType, 
        s.CatalogueSubType, s.EofE,
        s.EofEID, s.UserWhoCreated, s.DateCreated,  
        w.TechTeam, w.WorkflowSystemStatus, 
        w.NextActionByUser, w.CurrentStatus, w.NextActionBy, 
        NULL AS 'dummy1', NULL AS 'dummy2', NULL AS 'dummy3', 
        NULL AS 'dummy4'    
    FROM
        WorkflowTable w    
    INNER JOIN
        SETable s ON w.SecurityExceptionID = s.SecurityExceptionID    
    WHERE 
        w.currentstatus = 'Started' 
        AND w.WorkflowSystemStatus != 'SecurityTeamApproved' 
        AND w.NextActionBy = 'TechUser' 
        AND w.TechTeam = @techteam 
    ORDER BY  
        datecreated DESC
END
[setable_workflowtable] 'CloudTeam'
```

2nd procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[setable_setask]    
    @techteam nvarchar(100) = NULL    
AS    
BEGIN    
    IF (@techteam IS NULL OR @techteam = 'All')  
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            setask.*, 
            setable.SecurityExceptionInfoID, setable.CatalogueType, 
            setable.CatalogueSubType, setable.EofE, 
            setable.UserWhoCreated, setable.EofEID,  
            NULL AS 'dummy1', NULL AS 'dummy2', 
            NULL AS 'dummy3', NULL AS 'dummy4'    
        FROM
            SETask setask  
        INNER JOIN
            SETable setable ON setask.SecurityExceptionID = setable.SecurityExceptionID    
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            setask.*, 
            setable.SecurityExceptionInfoID, setable.CatalogueType, 
            setable.CatalogueSubType, setable.EofE, 
            setable.UserWhoCreated, setable.EofEID,  
            NULL AS 'dummy1', NULL AS 'dummy2', 
            NULL AS 'dummy3', NULL AS 'dummy4'    
        FROM
            SETask setask  
        INNER JOIN
            SETable setable ON setask.SecurityExceptionID = setable.SecurityExceptionID    
        WHERE 
            setask.TechTeam = @techteam  
        ORDER BY
            datecreated DESC
    END
END

EXEC [setable_setask] 'Cloudteam'
```

This is what I tried

```
CREATE PROCEDURE count
    @userTeam NVARCHAR(100),
    @Count1 INT OUTPUT,
    @Count2 INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC [dbo].[setable_workflowtable] @techteam = @userTeam;
    SELECT @Count1 = @@ROWCOUNT;

    EXEC [dbo].[SecondProcedure] @techteam = @userteam;
    SELECT @Count2 = @@ROWCOUNT;
END
```

I want my result to be like this

| Pending4Approval | Pending4Implementation |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 0 |

Comment: What what isn't working about the attempt you made? Why can't you just `SELECT` the results of `@Count1` and `@Count2`?

Comment: Your title is not very clear - why can't you select the two count values?

Comment: Sounds like you should make these procedures into inline Table Valued Functions, then you can just `SELECT COUNT(*)` from them

Comment: Why does the stored procedure need to know the count of results? Why can't the client process that's consuming the data figure it out from the received results?

Comment: "This is what I tried" what happened? And maybe just do `SELECT @Count1 AS Pending4Approval, @Count2 AS Pending4Implementation;`

Comment: @@rowcount should work just fine like you did. Unless you do some other stuff in the procedure after the last select which ruins it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Se_TechAdmin_Dashboard_Count( @username nvarchar(100))
AS
BEGIN 
     CREATE TABLE #TempTable1 ( SecurityExceptionID INT,
                                SecurityExceptionInfoID NVARCHAR(100),
                                WorkflowID INT,
                                CatalogueType NVARCHAR(100),
                                CatalogueSubType NVARCHAR(100),
                                EofE NVARCHAR(500),
                                EofEID INT,
                                UserWhoCreated NVARCHAR(250),
                                DateCreated datetime2(7),    
                                TechTeam NVARCHAR(50),
                                WorkflowSystemStatus NVARCHAR(100),
                                NextActionByUser NVARCHAR(100),
                                CurrentStatus NVARCHAR(100),
                                NextActionBy NVARCHAR(100),
                                dummy1 nvarchar(100) ,
                                dummy2 nvarchar(100) ,
                                dummy3 nvarchar(100) ,
                                dummy4 nvarchar(100) )
     INSERT INTO #TempTable1

EXEC [dbo].[setable_workflowtable] @techteam = @username 

     CREATE TABLE #TempTable2 (TaskID int,
                               [SecurityExceptionID] int,       
                               Taskcreatedby nvarchar(250),
                               TaskAssignedto nvarchar (250),
                               [TechTeam] nvarchar(250),
                               [TaskStatus] nchar(10),
                               [TaskCreatedDate] datetime2(7),
                               [TaskAssignedDate] datetime2(7),
                               [TaskExpectedCompletionDate] datetime2(7),
                               [TaskActualCompletedDate] datetime2(7),
                               [DateCreated] datetime2(7),
                               [DateModified] datetime2(7),
                               [TaskComments] nvarchar(1000),
                               [SecurityExceptionInfoID] nvarchar(50),
                               [CatalogueType] nvarchar(100),
                               [CatalogueSubType] nvarchar(100),
                               [EofE] nvarchar(500),
                               [UserWhoCreated] nvarchar (250),
                               [EofEID] int,
                               dummy1 nvarchar(100),
                               dummy2 nvarchar(100),
                               dummy3 nvarchar(100), 
                               dummy4 nvarchar(100))      
     INSERT INTO #TempTable2

EXEC [dbo].[setable_setask] @techteam = @username 

     DECLARE @Count1 INT, @Count2 INT
     SELECT @Count1 = COUNT(*) FROM #TempTable1
     SELECT @Count2 = COUNT(*) FROM #TempTable2
     SELECT @Count1 AS Pending4Approval, @Count2 AS Pending4Implementation
     DROP TABLE #TempTable1
     DROP TABLE #TempTable2
END

EXEC Se_TechAdmin_Dashboard_Count '''CloudTeam'',''SOCTeam'''
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**